# How do I calculate a percentage in Netlogo where the denominator will sometimes be zero?

Tags: netlogo, percentage, divide-by-zero

I am trying to set a variable as the percentage of an agentset that is within an agentset. Therefore, the programme is sometimes trying to divide by zero and I get an error message.

I have tried using an ifelse condition so that bit of code only runs when the denominator is more than 0. However, I still get the error message. Am I missing something in the following code?..

```
ifelse any? people with [recentvent? and trait = 1] 
[set %minority-affiliated-vents 100 * (count people with [groupid > 0 and recentvent? and trait = 1] / count people with [recentvent? and trait = 1])]
[set %minority-affiliated-vents 0]
```

I still get the division by zero runtime error.

Comment: Can you post your error message? I'm struggling to see why this code doesn't work. I think you may have an error elsewhere.

Comment: You do `any? people with [recentvent? and trait = 1]` in your `ifelse` check, but `* (count people with [groupid > 0 and recentvent? and trait = 1] / ...)`  My suspicion is you have cases where you have > 0 people with `recentvent? and trait = 1 ` but 0 people with `groupid > 0 and recentvent? and trait = 1`.  The extra `groupid > 0` is the likely cause of the divide by 0 error.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper . I do have some cases like that. However, the 'groupid > 0' condition only applies to the numerator, so it shouldn't produce the error. 0 divided by anything would just be 0.

Comment: Whoops, my bad!  Got confused on where the operations were happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. As a general approach, you can revise your code as follows - which reduces the number of times you need to construct the agentset, but also ensures you don't accidentally construct it differently between the test and using as the denominator. It is also a bit easier to read.

```
let test-agentset people with [recentvent? and trait = 1] 
ifelse any? test-agentset 
[set %minority-affiliated-vents 100 * count test-agentset with [groupid > 0] / count test-agentset]
[set %minority-affiliated-vents 0]
```

With this construction, you can see that the denominator cannot be zero, so the error must be elsewhere in your code.